# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3'

Tags: php, php-extension, php-7.4

I'm using docker for starting my web after I start my web I'm getting error

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/sqlite3 (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/sqlite3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/sqlite3.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

I verified : `apt list \*php\* --installed` and I found that sqlite3 is installed

[image]

`php -me`

[image]

Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY . /var/www/html
COPY ./docker/web/conf/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
RUN cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

RUN a2enmod headers rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php 

RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
    openssl \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    php-apcu \
    php-calendar \
    php-ctype \
    php-curl \
    php-dom \
    php-exif \
    php-fileinfo \
    php-fpm \
    php-gd \
    php-iconv \
    php-imagick \
    php-intl \
    php-json \
    php-ldap \
    php-mbstring \
    php-mysql \
    php-opcache \
    php-phar \
    php-posix \
    php-readline \
    php-shmop \
    php-simplexml \
    php-soap \
    php-sockets \
    php-sqlite3 \
    php-sysvmsg \
    php-sysvsem \
    php-sysvshm \
    php-tokenizer \
    php-xml \
    php-xmlreader \
    php-xmlwriter \
    php-xsl \
    php-zip \
    curl \
    php-zend-code \
    imagemagick \
  && apt-get clean -y 

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-dev libbz2-dev libssl-dev

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        intl \
    && apt-get purge -y \
        libicu-dev

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
        ghostscript --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install \
        imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
        imagick \
    && apt-get purge -y \
        libmagickwand-dev

WORKDIR /var/www/html

#CREATE ADMINISTRATOR CACHE FOLDER + FOLDER (tmp and log)
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/tmp && chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/tmp \
&& chown root:www-data /var/www/html/* -R;
```

Comment: What does your `Dockerfile` look like?

Comment: @Phil I add dockerfile